# How to handle webelement's id - not attribute id(!) in javascript from selenium-python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I need to handle webelements by identifying them uniquely.
Attribute id has known limitations: it might be missing and it might be non-unique.
There is a possibility to use evaluate, and I'm interested whether it's possible to identify elements by their id - not attribute id?

Please consider the following code:
I search element by its attribute id and then print its id - they are absolutely different

```
> Blockquote
>>> elem=driver.find_element(‘id’, ‘userInfoWhoRadioGroup_errorMessage’)
>>> elem.id
‘0ce5ef48-df80-487f-ada2-fc999dedb614’
>>> e.get_attribute(‘id’)
‘userInfoWhoRadioGroup_errorMessage’
>>>
> Blockquote
The beauty of the element's id is that every element has it and that it's unique.
```

Some more details: the elements I need to handle are already found using webdriver, I have them and their ids. Now I'd like to run javascript on them (without refreshing the page that would change the ids). And I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify them by these ids

Comment: `elem.id` has nothing to do with `< ... id="...">` - it can means unique ID of element in memory, not in HTML. I'm not sure if `elem.id` will not change if you reload page.

Answer (score 1):

HTML attribute <kbd>id</kbd> and <kbd>elem.id</kbd> are completely of 2 different things. The HTML id is specified in the HTML, where was `elem.id` is the `id` assigned to the element by selenium. This will be always unique and also changes when the page is refreshed/reloaded.

I would **not** recommend using <kbd>elem.id</kbd> for identification purpose.

You can interact with the element using the below

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent", elem)
```

Comment: The answer isn't helpful at all. It repeats what was stated in a question and gives unasked advice

Comment: Seems to be my second part is misisng in the answer. Have you tried using `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent", elem)`? Not sure why you want to use the elem.id when elem it self is a unique item.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Please accept the answer for the benefit of future readers and visitors.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, text of the answer isn't helpful. The real helpful answer is in the comment. If I accept the initial answer, people would construe that wrongly. Is it possible to update the answer - I would gladly accept it

Comment: It's been updated, after your confirmation on April 27th.